# Convert duration form seconds to ISO format in javascript

Tags: javascript, iso, duration

I want to convert duration time from seconds to ISO format, like this:

```
 5400 => 'PT1H30M'
```

I tried:

```
var isoDuration = moment.duration(5400,'seconds').toISOString();
alert(isoDuration);
```

But that doesn't work; in Chrome I get this error:

> Uncaught `ReferenceError`: `moment` is not defined

Any ideas?

Comment: moment is not defined? are you sure you've implemented the library correctly?

Comment: @MehulMohan thank you for your response.. Can you tell me how can I use this liberary ?

Comment: just load the `momentjs` library before your custom js file in your html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you were trying to use requires a library called Moment.js, which eases the difficulty of handling native `Date` objects in JavaScript.

You need to include the Moment.js library via a `<script>` tag in order to execute this code:

```js
var isoDuration = moment.duration(5400,'seconds').toISOString();
console.log(isoDuration);
```

```html
<!-- Include this tag somewhere *before* the code using `moment` runs -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with the rest of your project :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `moment.js` library.

```
// HTML
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>

// JS
var isoDuration = moment.duration(5400,'seconds').toISOString();
alert(isoDuration);
```

in action: https://jsfiddle.net/w1e13Lne/

result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```js
const t = new Date(1434343434 * 1000).toISOString();
console.log(t)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Comment: thanks @lukasz, this was super helpful and got me on the right track!